# Bridging Swift to Objective-C loses syntax highlighting, causes errors

Tags: objective-c, swift, xcode

In Xcode 8.2.1 I have mixed Objective-C code and Swift code, the Swift code's bridge to Objective-C mostly works (using the App-Swift.h file) but syntax highlighting is broken and I get brief errors during build (that go away after flashing).

I noticed that if I have some class `MyClass` declared in the Swift file and exposed via App-Swift.h that if I option-click on `MyClass` in an objective-C file (which is *not* syntax highlighted BTW) it doesn't just hot link *directly* to the App-Swift.h file as it should, it shows *two* interfaces that I can pick from: the original `MyClass` defined in the Swift file *and* the `MyClass` in the App-Swift.h file.

Anybody else experiencing this and have a solution?

Answer (score 1):

I find that `DerivedData` cleanup may help, it's alt + shift + cmd + k.

Remember to update to the newest xCode (at the time 8.3.2).

If this doesn't help, please try to minimize the test case and report to http://bugreporter.apple.com, so guys at Apple can know what doesn't work.